# How to play internet radio in Windows Phone 7?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have this URL "rtmp://203.146.251.6/live" for radio streaming.

How to play it on Windows Phone 7?

Comment: think Silverlight doesn't support RTMP protocol so you'd need to find 3d party library or implement it yourself